# I am getting a NullPointerException

Tags: nullpointerexception

```
private static Person[] createPersons(int N) {
    System.out.println("To be implemented - create "+N+" Person");
    Person person[] = new Person[N];

    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        System.out.println("error1");
        int age = 20 + i;
        String name = "Mr. Espresso" + i;
        final char gender = 'M';
        **person[i].setName(name);**
        person[i].setAge(age);
        person[i].setGender(gender);

    }
    return person;

public void setAge( int age ) {
    this.age = age;
}


/**
 * Sets the gender of this person.
 *
 * @param gender this person's age
 */
public void setGender( char gender ) {
    this.gender = gender;
}

/**
 * Sets the name of this person.
 *
 * @param age this person's name
 */
public void setName( String name ) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

I am trying to create a persons (object) array and fill it with values. However it gives a NullPointerException on person[i].setName(name); Can anyone explain me why?

setName/age/gender is referring to a method in the person object class. As seen below.

I've read the other articles, but I don't see it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: I may be taking crazy pills, but don't you need to invoke the constructor for each array element before use (person[i] = new Person())?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create each Person object in your person array.
You probably need above the error line something like
`person[i] = new Person();`